# Isomorphism: minimal number of steps to check

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

There are in general two methods to check a map is a isomorphism.

The first is to show it is injective, surjective and a homomorphism. A second way is via the construction of inverse.

I got kind of confussed about this second method because some people check more things than others. What are the minimal steps one has to make to follow this second method?

My guess is:

1. show $f$ is bijective
2. find $g$ such that $fg=id$

Are there any steps missing? That is, does it depend on the source some people are also checking things like surjectivity and injectivity of $g$? Is this necessary?

Comment: (1) implies (2).  If you want to show (1) from (2) then you also have to show there is $g$ so that $gf = id$ (both left and right inverses must exist.)

Comment: Existence of an inverse is equivalent to showing surjectivity and injectivity. You don't have to show both.  In practice the proofs often look very similar whether you show the existence of an inverse or show surjectivity and injectivity.

Comment: @JairTaylor so for the method via inverse one has to check:
First that there is a g such that gf=id=fg.
But also seeing the answer of Shaun it looks like one has to check some extra conditions on g and f ? Am I correct to say that the minimal conditions one has to check are that g and f are homomorphisms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "second way" is insufficient.

For example, a group isomorphism must map the identity in its domain to the identity in its codomain.

*Proof:* Let $x\in G$ and $\varphi: G\to H$ be a group isomorphism. Then

$$\begin{align} 
\varphi(x)&=\varphi(e_Gx)\\
&=\varphi(e_G)\varphi(x),
\end{align}$$

so if we multiply on the right by $(\varphi(x))^{-1}$, we get

$$\begin{align}
e_H&=\varphi(x)(\varphi(x))^{-1}\\
&=\varphi(e_G)(\varphi(x)(\varphi(x))^{-1})\\
&=\varphi(e_G)e_H\\
&=\varphi(e_G).
\end{align}$$

Since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, in particular, it is a bijection, so $e_G$ is the only $g\in G$ for which $\varphi(g)=e_H$.$\square$

But consider

$$\begin{align}
f: \Bbb Z_2&\to \Bbb Z_2,\\
[0]_2&\mapsto [1]_2,\\
[1]_2&\mapsto [0]_2.
\end{align}$$

Clearly $f$ has an inverse (namely, itself), but does not map the identity to the identity, so cannot be an isomorphism.

Comment: Is my correction in the comment I made on the comment of JairTaylor correct ?

Comment: The condition you're missing is that $f$ is a homomorphism, @B.D

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @Shaun , but to be absolutely sure (and also for other people reading this discussion). You mean that one does not have to check that g is a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, @B.D. Once $f$ is a bijection and a homomorphism, so is its inverse $f^{-1}$. This is a routine exercise. Try proving it. If you have any trouble, just let me know.